# Eliminate Nested View

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Please help me in optimizing the nested view. There are two views used in the below query which is very slow in performance.

```
SELECT  g.FID, a.ID,q.FID_ATTR AS UNITID
from  dbo.LINE AS g LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SECTION AS a ON g.FID_ATTR = a.FID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.V_UNITID as q on g.FID = q.FID 


CREATE view [dbo].[V_UNITID] as 
select
a.FID, a.FID_ATTR
from dbo.LINE as a left outer join  dbo.CONN as b on a.FID = b.FID_FROM 
left outer join
dbo.POINT as c on b.FID_TO = c.FID
where FLOW = 2
```

Comment: We need the table definitions, any keys or indexes and the query plan.

Comment: can't you remove the where clause, drop one of the views, and do your select on the view adding the where clause?

Comment: I nominate @MisterPositive to change his comment to an answer.

Comment: Nested views are a common way of killing your performance. They seem  so intuitive but they totally destroy the ability of the optimizer to generate a reasonable execution plan. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Answer (score 0):

Can't you remove the where clause, drop one of the views, and do your select on the remaing view adding the where clause?  ( the original question had 2 views )

Answer (score -1):

Please try the below,

**Views:**

- Try to remove where clause from the view definitions and merge two views into one

From my understanding, You can replace LEFT OUTER JOIN with INNER JOIN at main query as well as view definition, if possible.

With the understanding i got, Below is the query to try with. Please share more details about table structure, indexes, execution plan and complete output expected out of the query.

```
SELECT  
    g.FID, 
    a.ID,
    q.FID_ATTR AS UNITID,
    r.FID_ATTR As UNITID2
from  dbo.LINE AS g 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SECTION AS a 
    ON g.FID_ATTR = a.FID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.V_UNITID as q 
    on g.FID = q.FID AND q.Flow = 2
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.V_UNITID as r 
    on g.FID = r.FID AND r.Flow = 1


CREATE view [dbo].[V_UNITID] as 
select
    a.FID, 
    a.FID_ATTR,
    Flow
from dbo.LINE as a 
INNER JOIN dbo.CONN as b 
    on a.FID = b.FID_FROM 
INNER JOIN dbo.POINT as c 
    on b.FID_TO = c.FID
```